# Java Web Audio Api - how save base64Sting to audio file

Tags: javascript, java, audio, web, base64

I recorded sound using Web Audio Api, then convert blob to base64 (String) and send data on server. When I save this String to Audio File i can hear only noise - not this what I record. I try few way's how to save data to sound file and always had the same result.  someone know good way how to save base64String to audio file??

For example this string look like:

> data:audio/webm;codecs=opus;base64,T2dnUwACAAAAAAAAAACHNQAAAAAAAJEcMDUBE09wdXNIZWFkAQI4AUSsAAAAAABPZ2dTAAAAAAAAAAAAAIc1AAABAAAANIjAGwE2T3B1c1RhZ3MPAAAAbGlib3B1cyB1bmtub3duAQAAABMAAABFTkNPREVSPU1vemlsbGE2Mi4wT2dnUwAAgEMAAAAAAACHNQAAAgAAAGJxaOQVA/+a/1Dp5e/16eLe6+Pi4d7z/wnV/P/+/H/6yL2jIeFnQBUpdJsBUgQeO4DIfgJSzRcqs1rmJ+bVRCv5eH3+1c/pv6wZqbD26qYUuWs9Lzf8feT0pFjIacOaeyTplYTmiab+sqdx9jzGYEI4byxBxjF/oIxAI+eZ6f/buHL9QGKTDUq
>   .....

I also removed "data:audio/webm;codecs=opus;base64," before convert data to audio file.

Comment: tell us how you get on after you read up on :   "How to create an AudioBuffer from a Blob?"

Answer (score 0):

@ScottStensland I have this method which convert Blob to base64 for me:

```
    export function voncert(blob){
        var base64data;
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob); 
        reader.onloadend = function() {
            base64data = reader.result;               
            console.log(base64data);
        }
        return base64data;

}
```

Then i send this data to server and i try convert to audio file (in java).